# Ошибка при выведении 3d модели формата glb

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d

Всем здравствуйте!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Main</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normailze.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top">
                <div class="logo-url-vk">

                   <div class="logo">
                       <img src="img/Frame 24.png" alt="">
                   </div>
                   <div class="url-vk">
                       <a class="vk-a" href="#">Вконтакте</a>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="url-we">
                    <a class="url-we-a" href="#">Стать одним из нас</a><img src="img/Frame.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="top-main">
                <div class="icon">
                    <img src="img/Ресурс 3 2.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="main-text">
                    <h1 class="main-text-1">красивая жизнь. наша жизнь</h1>
                    <h1 class="main-text-2">обеспечен</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="url-tg">
                    <img src="img/Frame (2).png" alt=""><a class="tg-a" href="#">Узнай больше в telegram</a><img src="img/Frame (1).png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="end">
        <div class="blocks">
                <div class="block-1">
                    <img src="img/image 26.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="block-2">
                    <script type="importmap">
                        {
                            "imports": {
                                "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.0/build/three.module.js",
                                "OrbitControls": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js",
                                "GLTFLoader": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js",
                                "RectAreaLightHelper": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.0/examples/jsm/helpers/RectAreaLightHelper.js",
                                "RectAreaLightUniformsLib": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.0/examples/jsm/lights/RectAreaLightUniformsLib.js"
                            }
                        }
                    </script>
                    <script type="module">

        import * as THREE from 'three';
        import { OrbitControls } from 'OrbitControls';
        import { GLTFLoader } from 'GLTFLoader';
        import { RectAreaLightHelper } from 'RectAreaLightHelper'
        import { RectAreaLightUniformsLib } from 'RectAreaLightUniformsLib';

        function init() {
            

            //Scene
            const scene = new THREE.Scene()
            

            //Camera
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);
            camera.position.set(0, 0.5, 1)

            //render
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
            

            let plain;
            {
                plain = new THREE.Mesh(
                    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000),
                    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "#E2DFE1"})
                )
                plain.reciveShadow = true;
                plain.position.set(0, -1, 0)
                plain.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
                scene.add(plain)
            }

            // Model
            {
                const loader = new GLTFLoader();
                loader.load('ROLLS2.glb', gltf => {
                scene.add(gltf.scene);
                }, 
                    function (error) {
                        console.log('Error: ' + error)
                    }
                )
            }
            
            {
                const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)
                light.position.set(-2, 0, 10)
                light.lookAt(0, -1, 0)
                scene.add(light)

                // Helper
                // const helper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(light, 5)
                // scene.add(helper)
            }

            {
                const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)
                light.position.set(2, 0, 5)
                light.lookAt(0, 1, 0)
                scene.add(light)

                // Helper
                // const helper = new THREE.DirectionalLightHelper(light, 5)
                // scene.add(helper)
            }

            RectAreaLightUniformsLib.init();
            {
                const rectLight = new THREE.RectAreaLight(0xffffff, 1, 100, 100);
                rectLight.position.set(-10,0,0)
                rectLight.rotation.y = Math.PI + Math.PI/4;
                scene.add(rectLight)
            }

            {
                const rectLight = new THREE.RectAreaLight(0xffffff, 1, 100, 100);
                rectLight.position.set(10,0,0)
                rectLight.rotation.y = Math.PI - Math.PI/4;
                scene.add(rectLight)
            }
            
            //OrbitControls
            const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.autoRotate = true;
            controls.autoRotateSpeed = 5;
            controls.enableDamping = true;

            //Resize
            window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false)
            
            function onWindowResize() {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
            }

            // Animate
            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate)
                controls.update();
                renderer.render(scene, camera)
            }
            animate()

        }

        init()
    </script>
                </div>
                <div class="block-2">
                    <img src="img/image 27.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Появляются вот такие ошибки :
[image: ошибки]

Модель должна появится в центре,как в макете : https://www.figma.com/file/96eZmcvKEtLoGTaqQ0EDCZ/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD?node-id=0%3A1

Comment: поместите всей файлы на любой веб сервер и открывайте страницу через него, а не через открытие файла браузером

Comment: Локальный хостинг?

Comment: Открыл через локальный хостинг,но модель всё ещё не выводится